# How to improve speed of generic loop while reading from database

Tags: c#, database, generics

I have a mapping function that reads from the data loaded from the database. 
It maps onto a class that is through generic.

The problem is that it takes 3 minutes for looping through a 10000 records. 
I would like to improve its performance I am looking for a solution for this?

```
public static List<T> GetList<T>(string query = null, string whereClause = null, Dictionary<string, string> Params = null)
{
        var results = new List<T>();
        var properties = GetReadableProperties<T>();
        query = QueryMaker.SelectQuery<T>(query, whereClause);

        using (SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            Connection.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = GetSqlCommandWithParams(query, Connection, Params);
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                // From here 
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var item = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();

                    foreach (var property in properties)
                    {
                        DBReader(item, property, reader);
                    }

                    results.Add(item);
                }

                // To here. It takes 3 minutes. reading a 10000 record from database into reader isn't as slow as this code is.
            }

            Connection.Close();
            return results;
        }
}
```

This is the `DBReader` function:

```
private static void DBReader(Object _Object, PropertyInfo property, SqlDataReader reader)
{
        if (!reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal(property.Name)))
        {
            Type convertTo = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(property.PropertyType) ?? property.PropertyType;
            property.SetValue(_Object, Convert.ChangeType(reader[property.Name], convertTo), null);
        }
        else
        {
            property.SetValue(_Object, null);
        }
}
```

Comment: Seems like you are attempting to re-build an ORM. Why not use already built products such as Dapper (my personal favorite) or Entity framework?

Comment: Also, Activator.CreateInstance is kinda slow. Better use a generic condition on `T` `where T : new()` and just do `var item = new T();` instead. but probably what's slowing you down the most is the `DBReader(item, property, reader)` method which I assume is using reflection to populate a property of the item with a value from the data reader.

Comment: yes. Let me add the code for that too. Thankyou for the help

Comment: Yes this certainly does sounds like the perfect use case for dapper

Comment: My method was to create an array of property setters, which matches the reader field indexes, and then in the loop if the setter isn't null (the field was found), then set the field using the setter. Though, now that off-the-shelf libraries exist to do that, I'd advise using them.

Comment: You are reinventing the wheel. EF or Dapper would be better choice. That would take heck lot of time of you solving these issue.

Comment: Yes, Unfortunately I am not allowed to install Dapper (Or any other ORM) on the given software and must improve the speed of this loop. 
 @ZoharPeled
Thankyou for the help. I am going to use T();  that is faster

Comment: You do know that Dapper is an open source project, right? Take a look at what they did, and figure out how they made it work so fast.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I didn't know it is open source. i will go look at the source. Thankx

Comment: https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper Enjoy.

Comment: I would recommend profiling the code before you make assumptions about what's taking the most time. Reflection is "slow", but on my machine I'm still able to construct 1 million objects and set a property value on them using code practically identical to yours in under a second ([Linqpad example](http://share.linqpad.net/dohdu3.linq)). If your code is taking minutes to process ten thousand items, the bottleneck is probably somewhere you're not considering. Maybe the setters on your properties are doing something expensive, or maybe reading the values is taking longer than you think.

Comment: Did you run the performance profiler within visual studio??

Comment: It seems to be While reader.Read() is slowing it down and not the mapping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see a number of things you could theoretically improve. For example:

- store the result of GetOrdinal to reuse when getting values.
- use a generic `new()` instead of Activator.CreateInstance.
- Rather than using reflection, you could precompile an expression into a `Func<>` and invoke it for each row.
- Call the appropriate `Get...()` methods based on the desired type to avoid boxing and unboxing.

But *all of these are micro-optimizations* and even combining them all together is unlikely to make a significant difference. The amount of time you're describing (minutes for tens of thousands of rows) is unlikely to be caused by any of these kinds of issues. It's most likely coming from I/O operations somewhere, but it's impossible to be certain without profiling the code to see where the most time is being spent. Profile your code, and then use those results to inform what approach you take.

Comment: Thank you for the help. This time i  used SqlDataAdapter to fill the data. and mapped it to object later. The Adapter.Fill took a lot of time while the nested loop for  mapping to objects didn't even take a second.